# Can't get string vaules from an observable to put in another observable when using rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java

I aim to achieve connection of two followings;

1) Getting the string list of symbol variable which is sticked with foor value of "HOSE" from the url https://finfo-api.vndirect.com.vn/stocks.

2) Puting the string list at step 1) as the input of path for a retrofit service which I write and call VpbsService with the code:

I can achieve the step 1) but never pass step 2. The code for step 1) and step 2) are as belows

For step 1)

strSyms = getStrSymbols("HOSE").toString();

where `public static StringBuilder getStrSymbols(String floorName) {`

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    VndinfoService vndService = new RetrofitVndinfoService().create();
    vndService.vndGet()
            .map(u->u.getData())
            .toObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
            .filter(u->u.getFloor().equals(floorName))
            .map(s->s.getSymbol())
            .subscribe(u->sb.append(u + ","));
    return sb;
}
```

For step 2)
VpbsService vpbsService = new RetrofitVpbsService().create();

```
        Observable.interval(0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .flatMap(
                        i -> vpbsService.vpbsGet(strSyms)
                                .toObservable()
                )
                ..continue
```

urlBase for RetrofitVndinfoService is "https://finfo-api.vndirect.com.vn/", and urlBase for RetrofitVpbsService is "https://mobitrade.vpbs.com.vn:8080/".
In fact, I can connect two steps successfuly in java Eclipse but get fail in android. The problem is that strSyms don't contain any symbols. For VpbsService, I use

```
@GET("getliststockdata/{symbols}")
@Headers({"Accept: application/json"})
```

Speak clearly, for example, if strSyms = "AAA, APC," the url of "https://mobitrade.vpbs.com.vn:8080/getliststockdata/AAA,APC," can be accessed. In that case

```
        vpbsService.vpbsGet(strSyms) will work fine.
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem in your strSyms value. reactive streams doesn't work that way. your method will not wait for the event to return the value. you should do it like this.

```
public static Observable<StringBuilder> getStrSymbols(String floorName) {   
VndinfoService vndService = new RetrofitVndinfoService().create();
return vndService.vndGet()
        .map(u->u.getData())
        .toObservable()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
        .filter(u->u.getFloor().equals(floorName))
        .map(s->{StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); sb.append(s.getSymbol() + ","); return sb;})}
```

and then

```
Observable.interval(0, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .flatMap(
                    i ->  getStrSymbols("HOSE")
            ).flatMap(s -> vpbsService.vpbsGet(s)
                            .toObservable())
```

that is the rough flow. you can still simplify that imho

Comment: Thank you! @John . However, public static Observable<StringBuilder> getStrSymbols(String floorName) {   
VndinfoService vndService = new RetrofitVndinfoService().create();
return vndService.vndGet()
        .map(u->u.getData())
        .toObservable()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
        .filter(u->u.getFloor().equals(floorName))
        .map(s->{StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); sb.append(s.getSymbol() + ",")})} get error. The android studio notify that it miss ";". After adding ";" I still get error.

Comment: If I put `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();` before return statement and replace `vpbsGet(s)` by `vpbsGet(s.toString())`, the code will work fine. However, leak memory occurs after running android about two minutes.

Comment: I detect the reason why leak memory occur is that `flatMap(
                    i ->  getStrSymbols("HOSE")` can't only get the last item. Rather, it emits a sequences items continuously. For instance, it emits
 
AAA, (row 1)

AAA,AAM, (row 2)

AAA,AAM,ABT, (row 3)

......
I am trying to think a solution to get the last row but haven't overcome this obstacle yet. I hope you will give me a suggestion.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to return the string builder sb on the map() operator, already fixed it. I cant give you a suggestion because i don't have an idea what your code does and what your api returns and what do you need on those apis.

Comment: Thank you! @John I overcame that obstacle some days ago. The solution includes
`public static Single<List<String>> getStrSymbols(String floorName) {
        VndinfoService vndService = new RetrofitVndinfoService().create();
        return vndService.vndGet().map(u->u.getData()).toObservable()
             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .concatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
                .filter(u->u.getFloor().equals(floorName))
                .map(s->s.getSymbol()).toList();
    }`
Your code is great because it leads me to the final solution. Thank you!